# How to force cache deletion of a specific key in RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux, redux-toolkit

In RTK query - when I define my invalidation with invalidateTags - after I invalidate a particular key - it only refetches that data.

How can I delete cached data by invalidation or any other strategy.

The use case I have is this - I have a getter api which gives the details of an entity.

And another mutation API which is performing some action on this entity - which invalidates the getter key of the entity.

But when I am showing the detail of the entity "after the operation" - invalidation only causes isFetching to be true, isLoading is not true.

And showing stale data "while action is being performed" with old data will be an unsafe thing to do.

Hence I want to delete the cached data - "after the action" - so that the loader is shown.

Currently the "invalidation" of data is "soft invalidation" - is there a way to "hard invalidate" the "specific" cached data with "key"